# Funcion Random en Firestore , problema al conseguir peticiones no ordenadas

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firestore

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No soy capaz de recibir la respuesta a la petición a firestore de una forma aleatoria
alguna idea de como lograrlo?

Comment: Hola. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y coloca **el código como texto, no como imagen**. Las imágenes son difíciles de analizar en dispositivos pequeños. Si es posible, dinos también lo que has depurado y con qué resultados, poniendo puntos de interrupción en el código.

Comment: Que error se muestra en el LogCat, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Adjubta tu codigo en formato texto y no imagen

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas a todos , ya conseguí resolver el problema adjunto el código por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema y no es capaz de resolverlo en un futuro

Answer (score 0):

```
// inicio de la FUNCION de numeros random no repetidos
    int array_size=3; // cantidad de preguntas
    int arreglo[] = new int[array_size];
    int contador=0;

    //La clase random para generar los numeros aleatorios
    Random random=new Random();

    while(contador<array_size)
    {
        int temp = random.nextInt(5)+1; // cantidad de preguntas en ddbb
        int i;

        // comprovamos si ese valor ya existe en el array
        for (i=0;i<array_size-1;i++) {
            if (temp==arreglo[i]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // si no se encuentra, lo añadimos al array
        if (temp!=arreglo[i]) {
            arreglo[contador++]=temp;
        }
    }

    // mostramos el resultado
    for(int i=0;i<array_size;i++) {


        int finalI = i;
        database.collection("categories")
                .document(catId)
                .collection("questions")
                .whereEqualTo("index", arreglo[finalI])
                //.orderBy("index", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                //.startAfter(finalI1)
                .limit(1).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if (queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().size() < 10) {
                    database.collection("categories")
                            .document(catId)
                            .collection("questions")
                            .whereEqualTo("index", arreglo[finalI])
                            //.orderBy("index", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                            //.startAfter(finalI1)
                            .limit(1).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                Question question = snapshot.toObject(Question.class);
                                questions.add(question);
                            }
                            setNextQuestion();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Question question = snapshot.toObject(Question.class);
                        questions.add(question);
                    }
                    setNextQuestion();
                }

            }
        });
    } //añadido por el bucle
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).